# F# ignore missing ignore

Tags: f#, fsi

I am using F# often in a interactive way. I type statements in a script file in Visual Studio and press `Alt + Enter` to execute them in F# Interactive.
Very often I see the warning that I am ignoring the result of an expression. Of course I'm not, because I evaluate everything interactively.

Is there an option to turn this warning off?

Example:

```
let numbers = "151,160,137,91,90,15"
numbers.ToCharArray() 
|> Array.filter (fun e-> e=',')
|> Array.length
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! #nowarn "0020"
did it! :-)  Write an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

F# Interactive has various [options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233172.aspx) including one to suppress compiler warning messages:

```
--nowarn:<warning-list>
```

For more details see:

[/nowarn (C# Compiler Options)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f28x9z3.aspx)

As an example:

```
match [] with | a::b -> 0
```

F# Interactive returns

```
Script.fsx(9,7): warning FS0025: Incomplete pattern matches on this expression. 
For example, the value '[]' may indicate a case not covered by the pattern(s).

Microsoft.FSharp.Core.MatchFailureException: 
The match cases were incomplete at <StartupCode$FSI_0003>.$FSI_0003.main@() in
   C:\Users\Eric\Documents\Visual Studio2015\Projects\Workspace\Library2\Script.fsx:line 9 
Stopped due to error
```

For

```
#nowarn "25"
match [] with | a::b -> 0
```

F# Interactive returns

```
Microsoft.FSharp.Core.MatchFailureException: 
The match cases were incomplete at <StartupCode$FSI_0004>.$FSI_0004.main@() in 
  C:\Users\Eric\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Workspace\Library2\Script.fsx:line 9
Stopped due to error
```

Notice the warning is now gone.

To use `nowarn` you need to know the warning number which are like:

```
warning FS0025
```

It is the last digits of the warning code that you want to use with `#nowarn` and do not forget the quotes around the number.

So for FS0025 it is `#nowarn "25"`

Comment: #nowarn "20" fixes the "bind the result!"-warning. :-)